Get custom attribute value inside final_price.phtml for listing
I have code similar to the following in final_price.phtml. This code works to display my attribute value on product pages, but not in product listings. What do I need to do to get the same info in the product listing?
$product = $block->getSaleableItem();
$myAttribute = $product->getData('my_attribute');


I had "Used in Product Listing" set to "No" in Storefront Properties. I changed that to "Yes" and the values started showing up.
